# dis_max query isn't looking for the best matching clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm testing the dis_max query in the docs below:

```
PUT /blog/post/1
{
    "title": "Quick brown rabbits",
    "body":  "Brown rabbits are commonly seen."
}
PUT /blog/post/2
{
    "title": "Keeping pets healthy",
    "body":  "My quick brown fox eats rabbits on a regular basis."
}
```

This example is extracted from the book "Elasticsearch definitive guide" which explains that the answer from the query below would shows equals _score for both documents.

```
{ 
"query": {
    "dis_max": {
        "queries": [
            { "match": { "title": "Quick pets" }},
            { "match": { "body":  "Quick pets" }}
        ]
    }

}}
```

But, as you could see, the result from the query shows different _score.

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.02250402,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "blog",
      "_type" : "post",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 0.02250402,
      "_source" : {
        "title" : "Keeping pets healthy",
        "body" : "My quick brown fox eats rabbits on a regular basis."
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "blog",
      "_type" : "post",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.016645055,
      "_source" : {
        "title" : "Quick brown rabbits",
        "body" : "Brown rabbits are commonly seen."
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch is not returning the _score from best matching clause but is, somehow, blending the results. How may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer.

This confusing behavior happens because the index used in the example is using 5 shards (default number of shards).  And the _score is not calculated in the index as a whole but in individual shards and then are summarized before the user got the answer.

This problem is not a issue when you have a huge number of documents, what it is not my case.

So, to test my thesis, I deleted my index:

```
DELETE /blog
```

And then, created a new index using only 1 shard:

```
PUT /BLOG
{ "settings" : { "number_of_shards" : 1 }}
```

So, I performed my query again and got both documents with the same _score: 0.12713557

Sweet =)